# Rewrite URL Parameter containing dot

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, url-rewriting

I think that I am trying to achieve an impossible result.

The scenario is PURL-Mailing and I already got some URL's rewritten to fit the URL, sent to the customer.

The customer enters the site by the following domain: *http://domain.com/**UserName***

The Variable **UserName** represents the GET-Variable, which equivalent to *http://domain.com/index.php?user=**UserName***

I achieve this with the following rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1  [QSA] 
#This works perfect and translates to http://domain.com/UserName

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?name=$1 [L] 
#This achieves the goal but does not reflect in the URI I want:
#http://domain.com/UserName
```

To go further, there are also some Names containing a dot in the Name like **A.Jackson** that also need to be treated as **UserName**. As those are only 13 Name I could implement them manually. What I don't know is how I can prevent the part after the **dot** to be handled as a file extension. Is there a way to write a custom handle in *mod_rewrite* for those? 
And if so, can anybody explain to me how?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: Add dot to your regex `[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]`

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks but this causes an Internal Server Error. Doesn't work for me!

Comment: Because dot need to be escaped with \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok try below

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(img|anyother folders that you want to ignore|anyother folders that you want to ignore|...)
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[/]*$ test.php?name=$1  [L]
```

replace 'anyother folders that you want to ignore' with folder name that you want to ignore. Seperate each folders with '|'

You also have to provide full path to the CSS, image or any other links used in your web page when you using URL rewrite functions

Comment: Perfect Answer! Thanks a lot for your support! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your fix

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1  [L]
```

Comment: A step further: Is it also possible with an optional trailing slash? Like: http://www.jetztzuprimagas.de/A.Armbruster/

Comment: Instead of RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1  [L] use RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[/]*$ test.php?name=$1  [L]

Comment: Fine. Rewriting the URL works, but Ressources like Stylesheets seem not to be loaded anymore with an 404. For example Request for an image is now: http://www.jetztzuprimagas.de/A.Armbruster/img/img_teaser_1.jpg but intends to be http://www.jetztzuprimagas.de/img/img_teaser_1.jpg instead. Any solution for this?

Comment: Adding the suggestes snippet did'nt have the desired effect:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(img|font|css|download|js)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f    ...   implemented here: http://www.jetztzuprimagas.de/A.Armbruster/